# Create tag privilege unlocked at 1,499 repuation

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I don't want to claim this is a bug, however I'm curious to why I've been granted the "create new tags" privilege when I'm still under 1,500 rep?

[image]

My reputation doesn't appear to have fluctuated above and then below momentarily to unlock it..

[image]

Does the privilege (or other ones for that matter) just unlock when you're very close to the target?

Comment: At the top of that screenshot, it has "There were no reputation changes on this day". Meaning that your reputation actually did fluctuate today.

Comment: Someone had voted on one of your posts and retracted it, so you were temporarily above the threshold. Votes retracted on the same day they were cast are hidden from your history.

Comment: @animuson thanks, that would make sense i guess.